# UIPickerView inside a UIPopoverController memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I'm relatively new to iOS programing so I'll do my best to describe the problem I'm having. If I can provide some additional info to clear things up please tell me.

I'm currently displaying a UIPickerView within a UIPopoverController within my app. The problem I'm having is when I'm profiling with the leaks tool, every time the popover is dismissed a memory leak pops up. Here is the code for initializing the popover and the picker view.

```
// Show the popover
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[vc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 216)];

UIPickerView *pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pv setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[pv setDataSource:self];
[pv setDelegate:self];

[[vc view] addSubview:pv];
inputPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
[inputPopoverController setDelegate:self];
[pv selectRow:selection inComponent:0 animated:NO];
vc = nil;
pv = nil;

[inputPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cellRect inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

inputPopoverController is declared as

```
UIPopoverController *inputPopoverController;
```

And here's where I release the popover controller and I've confirmed that the function does get called every time the popover is dismissed.

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
inputPopoverController = nil;}
```

Instruments shows the leak at the following two locations

```
[pv selectRow:selection inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

and

```
[inputPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cellRect inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple days of breaking my head, it turns out I needed to implement one of the UIPickerView delegate methods. Here's where I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045423/ios6-uipickerview-memory-leak)